# Bitronix PoolingConnectionFactory vs SpringFramework CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: jms, connection-pooling, spring-jms, bitronix

Is there any difference between CachingConnectionFactory configured to have cache bigger than 1 and PoolingConnectionFactory?

I have seen both in various projects and I would like to understand the rationale behind choosing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case.

The bittronix factory pools connections and serves up a different connection for each use (and returns it to the pool).

The `CachingConnectionFactory` uses a single connection and caches sessions, producers, consumers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you able to give me some examples where CachingConnectionFactory  is a better choice and examples where PoolingConnectionFactory is a more suitable option?

Comment: Sorry, no; I don't know bitronix - I was just pointing out the differences in the actual implementations.

Answer (score 0):

That really is a strange question. Do you need XA? If yes, then you have no choice but to go with PoolingConnectionFactory. You don't need XA? Then don't bother with Bitronix and go with CachingConnectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plugable XA transaction managers like Bitronix (or Atomikos), use their pool implementations instead of Spring's because they perform additional operations like automatic enlisting in of resources in XA transactions.

Bitronix pools are:

- bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource for JDBC
- bitronix.tm.resource.jms.PoolingConnectionFactory for JMS

It's worth to take a look at the Bitronix test cases for examples how to setup the pools:

https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/test/java/bitronix/tm/mock/JmsPoolTest.java

https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm/src/test/java/bitronix/tm/mock/JdbcPoolTest.java